# Function/Expression to write values back in aggrid

Tags: ag-grid

I'm probably missing something in the documentation but cannot seem to find it right now.

Let's assume I have a data object like this:

```
{
  value1: number,
  value2: number,
  computed: number
}
```

Building an AgGrid that displays a set of these objects as rows with value1/2 being editable while computed is not editable is straightforward.

I can use expressions or functions to create a dynamic column which calculates e.g. `value1 * value2`. If I change `value1` or `value2` the dynamic column gets refreshed with the new values.

The question is, is there a way to bind the dynamic column to the `computed` field, or do I have to subscribe to row changes and do the updating of the `computed` field manually?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-change-detection/#example-change-detection-value-getters)

```
function getRowData() {
  var rowData = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    rowData.push({
      group: i < 5 ? "A" : "B",
      a: (i * 863) % 100,
      b: (i * 811) % 100,
      c: (i * 743) % 100,
      d: (i * 677) % 100,
      e: (i * 619) % 100,
      f: (i * 571) % 100,
      t:1000 <--- added 
    });
  }
  return rowData;
}
```

and in `columnDefs`

```
{
    headerName: "Total",
    valueGetter: "data.t = (data.a + data.b + data.c + data.d + data.e + data.f)",
    editable: false,
    aggFunc: "sum",
    cellClass: "total-col"
},
{
    field: "t",  -- just for test
}
```

So everything handled here

```
valueGetter: "data.t = (data.a + data.b + data.c + data.d + data.e + data.f)",
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/DE5e3jZmccNCuKWX)</kbd>

Comment: thanks, the "data.t =" in the value getter did it,  didn't expect the expression to be able to set something in a getter and missed that part in the docs.